# Unexpected behaviour of PHP strripos function

Tags: php, debugging, ascii, extended-ascii

Tracking the cause of a mysterious bug in my program, eventually i discovered this unexpected behaviour of PHP's strripos function:

Test code (Tested with PHP 5.4.24):

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

echo 'strripos: ';
var_dump(strripos(chr(128), chr(128)));

echo '<br>strrpos: ';
var_dump(strrpos(chr(128), chr(128)));

echo '<br>strpos: ';
var_dump(strpos(chr(128), chr(128)));

echo '<br>stripos: ';
var_dump(stripos(chr(128), chr(128)));

?>
```

Its output:

```
strripos:

boolean false


strrpos:

int 0


strpos:

int 0


stripos:

int 0
```

This occurs when the needle argument is a single byte with ASCII code above 127.

I am not sure if this is a bug or not.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php *"Warning
This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function."*

Comment: `var_dump(strripos(chr(128), chr(128)));` returns `int(0)` for me on php 5.6. What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: If you think it's a bug, you can submit a (bug) report https://bugs.php.net/report.php?bug_type=Documentation+problem&manpage=function.strripos

Comment: I tested it with PHP 5.4.24